# ruby case statement with strings doesn't work (as expected)

Tags: ruby, string, switch-statement

```
case 'this is not a test' 
  when 'this is not a test'.eql?('this is not a test')
    p '1' 
end
```

This does not match.

I've also tried:

1. `my_var = 'this is not a test'` and changing the `case` statement appropriately.
2. doing #1 coupled with various `"#{my_var}"` tries.
3. printing everything to see if anything is returning anything weird (nil, etc.)
4. using IRB to test 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Try writing just `when 'this is not a test'` and it should work. Lots of questions on SO about how the case-expression works.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I'll grant you that it's bloated.  I see that now.  But see 1) on my list.  If I do case my_var ... when my_var.eql?('this is not a test') it still fails.  I feel like this could be confusing to more Ruby newbs than just myself.

Comment: See "[mcve]" and particularly Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". Your question lacks backing code. Instead of describing what you're doing, show us the minimal code necessary to demonstrate each point. `case` and `when` are some of the most tested code, and they're easily used so we need very clear examples of the problem. "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" is useful to read also.

Comment: As a note `.eql?` isn't really intended to be used this way. Use `x == y` unless you have a very good reason to force `x.eql?(y)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it does not match.

- `'this is not a test'.eql?('this is not a test')` evaluates to `true`.
- `case x when y .... end` evaluates to `if y === x ... end`.
- `true === 'this is not a test'` evaluates to `false`.

You either wanted `case when x ... end`, which evaluates to `if x ... end`, a slightly different syntax with a different semantics:

```
case
  when 'this is not a test'.eql?('this is not a test')
    p '1' 
end
```

or, if you're happy with `===` instead of `eql?`, you can write

```
case 'this is not a test'
  when 'this is not a test'
    p '1' 
end
```

Comment: I understand what your saying, but here's my last-leg-to-stand-on:  if you look at 1) from my numerical list in my question: how about when my_var = 'this is not a test' ... when my_var.eql?('this is not a test').  Because to me, if I call an equals method on a variable such that the parameter passed to the equals method is the same value in length and content as what is stored to my variable...the return value should be true.  In fact, this is taken directly from the Ruby core 2.4.1 docs: _Two strings are equal if they have the same length and content._

Comment: The return value of `.eql?` *is* true. You're just comparing this `true` again with the string, and *that* is false. There is no difference if you use a variable or a string, the problem is you are doing two comparisons while thinking you're doing only one.

Comment: I guess I need to read up more on switch statements and in particular Ruby's, but I must admit that although I follow your logic I still see merit in my argument and find the Ruby presentation both frustrating and misleading.

Comment: I don't see the merit in your argument, and I'm running out of ways to show you what's happening. The calculation that is happening is this: `("foo".eql?("foo")) === "foo"`, and it is `false`. I mean, Ruby spells it out in plain English: "case when foo is equal to foo is equal to foo".

Comment: Okay, fair enough.